# Ambiguous call on an Action<T> where T inherits 2 interfaces having the same method signature

Tags: c#, interface, delegates, expression-trees, multiple-inheritance

I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Action<Child> aFoo = a => a.Foo();
    }
}

interface Parent1
{
    void Foo();
}

interface Parent2
{
    void Foo();
}

interface Child : Parent1, Parent2
{

}
```

However, the compiler tells me that I have an ambiguous call on `aFoo`.

I tried to do `Action<Child> aFoo = (A a) => a.Foo();` but it tells me that I cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type `System.Action<Child>`

How do I resolve the error of ambiguity?

Comment: Declaring `aFoo` as `Action<B>` or `Action<A>` would fix the first problem.

Comment: What is the relation of `A` and `Child`? The error suggests that they're not compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By casting the value of `a` inside the body of the lambda:

```
Action<Child> aFoo = a => ((Parent1)a).Foo();
```

Your attempted solution did not work because it did something else entirely: it tried to fit a *lambda expression* taking a `Parent1` into a *delegate* taking a `Child`. This is not possible, even though it *is* possible to fit a *delegate* taking a `Parent1` into a delegate taking a `Child`:

```
Action<Child> aFoo = (Action<Parent1>)(a => a.Foo());
```

This latter usage is viable because `Action<T>` is contravariant on the type T.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to ask another question in relation to Moq, which is the reason why I asked this. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932493/moq-setup-invalidcastexception-when-mocking-an-interface-that-inherits-from-mult

Answer (score 2):

`Action<T>` is not covariant in its type parameter `T`, it is contravariant.
That means `Action<object>` can be converted to `Action<string>`, but not the other way around.

Generally put, `Action<T>` is a subtype of (read: can be assigned to) `Action<U>`, only if `U` is a subtype of `T`.

In your case, `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`, which means `Action<Parent>` is a subclass of `Action<Child>`, allowing you to do this:

```
Action<Child> a = new Action<Parent> (... );
```

But not:

```
Action<Parent> a = new Action<Child>( ... );
```

That being said, try casting the lambda parameter instead:

```
Action<C> aFoo = a => ((A)a).Foo();
```

Comment: I don't see how covariance applies.

Comment: @DStanley updated, it should be clearer now. The lack of covariance is why `Action<Child>` cannot be assigned to `Action<Parent>`.

Comment: Kind of a coincidence, but `Action` is actually the example cited on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)